# Conditional Indentation in Vim

Tags: vim

How would i assign my own indentation margin if a condition is met (ie *string* is included) on the previous line?
An example would be one space indentation in an *if* statement. thanks in advance.

input:

`int main(int argc, char **argv) {

if (argc != 1)
    return(2);

```
if (argc != 2)
   return(3); 

for (...)
```

printf("\n");
}`

output:(using g/if/normal j>>)
shifts to the right every *return* line

output:(expected)

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
if (argc != 1)
 return(2);

if (argc != 2)
 return(3);   

for (...)
```

printf("\n");
}

In other words the positioning is expected to be relative to the string, and not its previous position. again, thanks for your effort @kev

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
:help indentexpr
```

You need to create a indent function.

I've used the following reference before.
[How to Write a Vim Indent Script](http://psy.swan.ac.uk/staff/carter/Vim/vim_indent.htm)

You can also look in the indent folder of your vim install for examples.

on Max OS X

```
/usr/share/vim/vim73/indent
```

Answer (score 1):

Use these commands to auto indent C source file:

```
:set syn=cpp
```

<kbd>g</kbd><kbd>g</kbd><kbd>=</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>

Comment: it's a nice guideline, but i think it's not as solid as i need. seems to shift the next line from its current indentation. my enquiry was to shift one just after the if's position whatever the position of the line is.

Comment: @angelobodas: Would you post a sample(input and output)?

Comment: couldnt indent code in comment so i had to reedit the question.

Comment: this will apply the indentation globally even to lines that don't match the _string_. say you have an _if_ statement which will be indented as expected and a _for_ loop which will also be indented, which is not what we want.

Comment: voted up as it can be helpful answer or guide to related questions.